# Add or Remove Multiple checklist items to another list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 2 div with Multiple check boxes and 2 Buttons Add and Remove.
Checking some items and clicking add I want to update them to 2nd div with no repeat values and same process for remove.

I tried to do this but not able to make it properly.
I tried as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-add').click(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
            $('.chk-container-Add').append("<li><input class="checkbox2" type="checkbox" value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</li>");
            $(this).remove();
 // Has to be added in div2 and removed from div1
});
   });

    $('#btn-remove').click(function(){
       //Has to remove from div2 and to be added in div1
    });

});
```

Here is my fiddle demo

http://jsfiddle.net/M_Sabya/xuktz0j7/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to move the checkboxes alone — or, rather, re-create them — when you want to move the `li` items containing them.

```js
$('#btn-add').click(function() {
  $('.chk-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    $(this).
      prop('checked', false).
      closest('li').appendTo($('.chk-container-Add'));
  });
});

$('#btn-remove').click(function() {
  $('.chk-container-Add input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    $(this).
      // uncheck as we move
      prop('checked', false).
      // find the parent <li>
      // append to the other container
      // no need to remove
      closest('li').appendTo($('.chk-container'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1">
  <ul class="chk-container">
    <li>
      <input class="ck1" type="checkbox" value="item1">Item 1</li>
    <li>
      <input class="ck1" type="checkbox" value="item2">Item 2</li>
    <li>
      <input class="ck1" type="checkbox" value="item3">Item 3</li>
    <li>
      <input class="ck1" type="checkbox" value="item4">Item 4</li>
    <li>
      <input class="ck1" type="checkbox" value="item5">Item 5</li>
    <li>
      <input class="ck1" type="checkbox" value="item6">Item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id="btn-add">Add &raquo;</button>
<button id="btn-remove">&laquo; Remove</button>
<div id="div2">
  <ul class="chk-container-Add">
    <li>
      <input class="ck1" type="checkbox" value="item7">Item 7</li>
    <li>
      <input class="ck1" type="checkbox" value="item8">Item 8</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.parent()`, because `$(this)` is the checkbox itself.

Also, you have used double quotes which gives you syntax error:

```
.append("<li><input class="checkbox2" type="checkbox" ...
```

You should escape double quotes in your string, or use single quotes as below:

```
.append("<li><input class='checkbox2' type='checkbox' ...
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn-add').click(function(){
        $('#div1 input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
            $('.chk-container-Add').append("<li><input class='checkbox2' type='checkbox' value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).parent().text()+"</li>");
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });

    // it's basicaly the same as the above, except of the container, which is "div2"

    $('#btn-remove').click(function(){
        $('#div2 input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
            $('.chk-container').append("<li><input class='checkbox2' type='checkbox' value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).parent().text()+"</li>");
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });

});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ed4s1xx2/)